# How to change the class so that the method does not change any colours unless the list contains both red and green

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
 class ColourChanger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.colour_replacement = {'red': 'black', 'Red':'Black',  'green': 'white', 'Green': 'White' }

    def make_readable(self, colours):
        result = []
        new_dict = {'red': 'black', 'Red':'Black', 'green': 'white', 'Green': 'White'}
        for col in colours:
            if col in self.colour_replacement:
                if  col in new_dict:
                    result.append(self.colour_replacement[col])

            else :
                if not col in new_dict:

                    result.append(col)

        return result
c = ColourChanger()
print(c.make_readable(['red', 'green', 'white', 'pink', 'yellow', 'red']))
print(c.make_readable(['red', 'Green']))
print(c.make_readable(['red', 'red', 'yellow', 'Red']))
```

So far I tried to create a new_dict with the words red and green, but I can't make it skip the line if it does not contain red and green any ideas? Tnx.

The output I get is:

```
['black', 'white', 'white', 'pink', 'yellow', 'black']
['black', 'White']
['black', 'black', 'yellow', 'Black']
```

The output desired is:

```
['black', 'white', 'white', 'pink', 'yellow', 'black']
['black', 'White']
['red', 'red', 'yellow', 'Red']
```

Comment: what about writing `if-else` condition within your function?

Comment: new_dict is the dict I created with the values it should search for

Answer (score 0):

```
class ColourChanger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.colour_replacement = {'red': 'black', 'Red':'Black',  'green': 'white', 'Green': 'White' }


    def make_readable(self, colours):
        if not all(i in colours for i in ["red", "green"]):
            if not all (i in colours for i in ["red", "Green"]):
                return colours

        result = []
        new_dict = {'red': 'black', 'Red':'Black', 'green': 'white', 'Green': 'White'}
        for col in colours:
            if col in self.colour_replacement:
                if  col in new_dict:
                    result.append(self.colour_replacement[col])

            else :
                if not col in new_dict:

                  result.append(col)

        return result
c = ColourChanger()
print(c.make_readable(['red', 'green', 'white', 'pink', 'yellow', 'red']))
print(c.make_readable(['red', 'Green']))
print(c.make_readable(['red', 'red', 'yellow', 'Red']))
```

This is the final code, tnx AkshayNevrekar